# Jquery - How to get content html div except class "active"

Tags: jquery, html

i have a div like this :

```
<div class="exmaple">
   <a class ="active">first</a>
   <a class>second</a>
   <a class>third</a>
</div>
```

I want to get content html of div class "example" except content of class "active" by jquery.

The results should be: `"<a class>second</a><a class>third</a>"`. Thanks everyone.

Comment: you want them in a console log?

Comment: Yes. The result is in console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is to clone the element, remove the active class, then get the inner html.

```js
var content = $('.example').clone().find(".active").remove().end().html()

console.log(content)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
   <a class ="active">first</a>
   <a>second</a>
   <a>third</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use querySelectorAll and simply exclude the class you don't want. This results in returning the second and third 'a' elements - and you are able to use CSS selectors - and therefore the :not selector.

```js
var content = document.querySelectorAll('.example a:not(.active)');

console.log(content)
```

```html
<div class="example">
   <a class ="active">first</a>
   <a>second</a>
   <a>third</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Or even better, `$(".example>*:not(.active)")`, since the he asked for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("div a").not(".active"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="exmaple">
   <a class ="active">first</a>
   <a class>second</a>
   <a class>third</a>
</div>
```